# Passing Data Multiple ViewControllers Forward

Tags: ios, core-data, model-view-controller

What would be an acceptable way to pass data more than one ViewController forward? For example, I currently have an iPhone app with Core Data. The Core Data is set up in the AppDelegate class, and the initial ViewController is ViewController A. ViewController A doesn't interact with Core Data, but it segues to ViewController B, which does interact with Core Data and requires variables (NSManagedObjectContext) set up in the AppDelegate. How could I pass the information from the AppDelegate to ViewController B?

I've read that singletons aren't good practice, so would it make sense to just pass the variable to ViewController A and then pass it on to ViewController B? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singletons are just fine! Don't let anyone scare away from their ***proper*** use.

It's true that they can be misused, but it makes more sense to store data in a central location than to pass data long a chain of view controllers that make no use of the data, **just in case** a view controller down the line needs it!

Make sure you follow Apple's design patterns and you should be fine.

Here's the typical way to instantiate a singleton instance of a class:

```
+ (instancetype)singleton {
    static <ClassName> *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singleton = [[<ClassName> alloc] init];
        // If you have any other, one-time configuration that you 
        // don't handle in "init", also do it here
    });
    return singleton;
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! I can make a method similar to this to get the context from the AppDelegate and use that.

Comment: I'd make it a separate class. AppDelegate should really be left alone to do its job. It's very easy to make a separate class to hold the data you need.